# How large a deflected missile can I catch in one hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, ranged-attack

When using deflect missiles, how big must a weapon be to not be able to catch it in one hand? Javelins, for example, are thrown with one hand, so maybe can be caught with one hand.

Comment: The question is about the size of the missile in general, not mattering who or what shot/threw it.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [What is the maximum size of missile a monk can deflect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104792/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-missile-a-monk-can-deflect)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no thrown 2-handed weapons, so anything thrown is considered one handed, meaning you can catch it one handed.

As for anything outside of the regular weapon tables, the answer is the same thing it always is:

Talk to your DM. If it seems reasonable, they're probably going to allow it.

Comment: The question is about size, which you completely ignore. What if it's a one-handed weapon sized for a giant? Your logic would suggest that you can catch literally anything as long as there exists some being in the world for which it can be wielded one-handed. And what about improvised thrown weapons?

Comment: The original answer to this question addressed weapons. Since the weapons in the book are only covered in the PHB, that was what I addressed. Like every 5e answer, if it isn't covered in the rule books, the answer is always, "Talk to your DM." I've added that to my answer for clarification.