# What is the maximum size of missile a monk can deflect?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, ranged-attack

What is the maximum size of missile a monk can deflect? Not catch, just deflect. e.g. A boulder from a trebuchet.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [How large a deflected missile can I catch in one hand?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65846/how-large-a-deflected-missile-can-i-catch-in-one-hand)

Answer (score 20):

*Player's Handbook* p.78:

> **Deflect Missiles**
>
> [...] you can [...] deflect or catch the missile when you are hit by a ranged weapon attack.
>
> [...] you can catch the missile if it is small enough for you to hold in one hand [...]

### Deflect

As long as it's a missile from a **ranged weapon** attack, you can deflect it.

### Catch

Since you are able to hold (not use) a two-handed weapon in one hand the missile can be pretty big. Unclear cases have to be decided by the DM.

### Example

The **Trebuchet** *(DMG, p.256)* makes a **ranged weapon attack**, thus a monk would be able to **deflect** it. Due to common sense, I would argue that you are not able to hold the boulder in one hand and thus are **not able to catch it**.

Comment: Of course, if the monk was polymorphed into a great ape ...

Comment: @DaleM If the monk were polymorphed into a giant ape, they would lose their monk class features and be unable to deflect or catch it. Druid Shapeshifting or the Shapechange spell are the only ways to change form I'm aware of that retain class abilities.